# how to add menu in eclipse MenuBar through eclipse plugin from java File

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add my menu in eclipse through eclipse plug-in development but not through plugin.xml. I want to use java code, as we can do the same by using IWorkBenchWindowPullDown interface for adding pulldown menu.
So what is the way to add menu in menuBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation of [MenuManager](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/MenuManager.html). You could get the MenuManager via WorkbenchWindow.getMenuManager()

Comment: Just a note, this is considered using internals.  It won't work reliably in 3.x, and definitely not in Eclipse 4.x

Comment: @Paul, you're right. It uses internal class, can't make sure it work in future release.

Answer (score 1):

As above, you can use **org.eclipse.ui.menus** and add a menuContribution that includes a dynamic element.  Then you can return whatever IContributionItems you would like from your implementation of CompoundContributionItem.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Menu Contributions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Problems_View_Example). Scroll down for Menus API.